# Extracting duplicates and non existing values in a dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I am new to pandas.

I have 2 datasources - A and B.

Both A and B have one column and have the following data:

A

```
Cj0KCQiAiZPvBRDZARIsAORkq7fOa9HW8u6iqLm1KvTjAhWTrYoLeL_baPPO5WoiLHsHeVYUmFFxXa0aAvxKEALw_wcB
EAIaIQobChMImLDtsuSY5gIVR3RgCh1ckQ1fEAAYASAAEgJ4nvD_BwE
Cj0KCQiAiZPvBRDZARIsAORkq7fOa9HW8u6iqLm1KvTjAhWTrYoLeL_baPPO5WoiLHsHeVYUmFFxXa0aAvxKEALw_wcB
Cj0KCQiAiZPvBRDZARIsAORkq7enWHEermCPb4NKdGwnh2HQwUPftxai7nufoVPOgDHE8CE9_s0hSAIaArPJEALw_wcB
Cj0KCQiAiZPvBRDZARIsAORkq7fQm2PgqtRHrXGkzcBPsZo-1Rwm4Ln6RuSBLumtNeElnoASiyC49HAaAoTWEALw_wcB
```

B

```
EAIaIQobChMI_tf0seSY5gIViKztCh1TbAAhEAAYASAAEgKcg_D_BwE
EAIaIQobChMImpyb_-OY5gIVET5gCh38Kw3bEAAYBCAAEgLmHfD_BwE
Cj0KCQiAiZPvBRDZARIsAORkq7fnlXGP7pfobqU5VFzlMPdPSjCKzSE6n43QSnkbQ264SVnX9kkSyHAaApudEALw_wcB
EAIaIQobChMIwvGQt-SY5gIVh6ztCh1c0gHQEAAYAyAAEgLqvPD_BwE
Cj0KCQiAiZPvBRDZARIsAORkq7ej_kXsK5XGwISOQTWUZoChlugerRH0Wcz4Wrpn1qJzlIkKxwqljCsaAhRNEALw_wcB
```

I concat the frames to one column like this:

```
joined = pd.concat([A,B])
```

And get one column with both sources.
Next I create new dataframe, store `joined` in the first column and `B` to the second column.

```
final_export = pd.DataFrame()
final_export['A'] = joined
final_export['B'] = B
```

And the dataframe looks like this:

final_export

```
A                                                         B
EAIaIQobChMI_tf0seSY5gIViKztCh1TbAAhEAAYASAAEgKcg_D_BwE   EAIaIQobChMI_tf0seSY5gIViKztCh1TbAAhEAAYASAAEgKcg_D_BwE 
EAIaIQobChMImpyb_-OY5gIVET5gCh38Kw3bEAAYBCAAEgLmHfD_BwE   EAIaIQobChMI_tf0seSY5gIViKztCh1TbAAhEAAYASAAEgKcg_D_BwE
EAIaIQobChMIwvGQt-SY5gIVh6ztCh1c0gHQEAAYAyAAEgLqvPD_BwE
EAIaIQobChMI_tf0seSY5gIViKztCh1TbAAhEAAYASAAEgKcg_D_BwE
EAIaIQobChMImpyb_-OY5gIVET5gCh38Kw3bEAAYBCAAEgLmHfD_BwE
EAIaIQobChMIwvGQt-SY5gIVh6ztCh1c0gHQEAAYAyAAEgLqvPD_BwE
...
```

Column A has more entries than column B.

Then I am creating new Dataframe which has 3 columns - In both, Only in A, Only in B. The logic is that I have one list with all values and I need to check if the value exists in both sources, and values existing only in one source will be placed in either only A or only B column:

```
df_export = pd.DataFrame({'In both': pd.Series(np.intersect1d(final_export['A'], final_export['B'])),
                          'Only in A': pd.Series(np.setdiff1d(final_export['A'], final_export['B'])),
                          'Only in B': pd.Series(np.setdiff1d(final_export['B'], final_export['A']))})
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I have tried using `.fillna('')` to column B because it has less entries than column A but am still getting the same error.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Is that really pd.concat(A,B) and not pd.concat([A,B])? Also what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve to know if value from source A exists in source B and vice versa. The output .csv file will have 3 columns, `in both` stating that value found in A exists in B and value from B exists in A, `in A` stating that value was only exists in source A and `in B` stating that value only exists in source B. And yes, I am concatinating with [ ].

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in pure python then create the dataframe - so:

```
setA = set(A)
setB = set(B)
both = setA & setB
only_in_A = setA - both
only_in_B = setB - both
```

Then create the dataframe as in

```
tuples = [(item, item in both, item in only_in_A, item in only_in_B) 
          for item in setA | setB]
df = pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=['value', 'in_both', 'in_A', 'in_B'])
```

Comment: I am able to have the `true` / `false` values, I need to list the items that do or do not exist in the combined sources.

Comment: Then you could list those items with `df.loc[df.in_A, 'value']`